# How to save selected with kartik-Select2 widget items to DB in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-select2, yii2

My issue is the following.
I am trying to insert multiple items to mysql database table. I use Kartik-Select2 widget for item selection.
The following code is working for me and I can select multiple items with it.

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'categories')->widget(Select2::className(), [
    'data' => $model->availableCategories(),
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'categories',
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select a site...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'multiple' => true,
        ],
    ]) ?>
```

But how now to save selected items to DB table. Where selected items stored (is there some array for them inside the widget)?
My 'categories' attribute defined in Model class as:

```
public $categories = [];
```

I thought selected items will populate to it. But it does not work (array is empty after form submition). I read many similar topics but did not find complete and full explanation how it works. I am new in Yii2 and maybe lost smth. Thx for any help.

Comment: show your action (controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally a multi select items is saved this way   ( this is a simplified way )

```
  public function actionYourAction()
  {
      $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

      if (!empty($post)){

          $postModel = $post['YourModel'];
          $postModelMulti=  $postModel['your_multi_attribute'];

          if ( !empty( $postModelMulti) ){
              foreach ($postModelMulti as $key => $value) {

                  $newModel  = new YuorModelToAdd();

                  $newModel->your_attribute = $value;

                  $newModel->save();
              }
          }  
      } 
      ......
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answer. It helped me to find an answer.

Comment: This is helpful for me as well.